# Using shell_exec with PHP only returns "not found" errors

Tags: php

When using shell_exec() to trigger any command on my system I am greeted with a "not found" error in my logs, but this doesn't happen wit hall commands.

I can use `shell_exec( 'dig google.com' );` and get a proper output, but when I try to trigger `shell_exec( '/path/to/my.sh param1 param2' );` I end up with

```
sh: /path/to/my.sh: not found
```

I'm at quite a loss, I originally intended to generate a new user this way with some clever usage of the adduser command on Debian, but not even that command was found when PHP tried triggering it (same error as with my own custom shell script file so I had `sh: adduser: not found`)

On the test environment the apache session uses ITK to run as root, and I've also ensured that my own shell script has the right permissions and is executable

Running PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze14 with Zend 2.3.0 and Suhosin 0.9.32.1

Comment: Are you sure the path to your shell file is correct? Btw `adduser` is in `/usr/sbin`. The directories `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin` are probably not in your `$PATH`-variable (these are only added if you're root, check out `/etc/profile`).

Comment: @vstm Yes I've checked that the path to my script file is correct, I've also confirmed that it works by triggering the exact command I pass in my `shell_exec` as a stand alone command in my shell.

Comment: Have you verified that the PHP-script is executed as root (`/usr/bin/id`)? If not, does the user of the process have read/execute rights to all directories in your path? Do you have SELinux enabled?

Comment: @vstm There is no SELinux running on the box, a `whoami` informs me that I am, in fact, running as root (as was the intention). I've also set ownership of my files to root from the get-go.

Answer (score 0):

Just try `exec()` instead of `shell_exec()` for executing the commands. It will work

Comment: Unfortunately, the outcome of `exec()` is identical to `shell_exec()`.